# findall for fuzzy regexp in python using TRE

Tags: python, regex, fuzzy-search

I am using [TRE](https://github.com/laurikari/tre/) for fuzzy regexp in python, however, TRE seems to find only the first appearance and it has no "findall" method to find all appearances of the regexp.

The code I am looking for should look like this:

```
import tre
pt = tre.compile('[0-9]{2}.[0-9]{2}.20[0-9]{2}', tre.EXTENDED)
fz = tre.Fuzzyness(maxerr=2)
m = pt.findall(text, fz)
```

but, of course I get a error because "findall" is not available.

Is there any other option to do fuzzy regexp and find all matches?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a global option? Why not use the normal Python regex.

Comment: I use TRE to do fuzzy regex, is it possible to do "fuzzy" with normal Python regex?

Comment: hey, did you ever figure out how to do findall with TRE?

Comment: I could not found a way